# How to send query parameters for gmail api for list_user_messages?

Tags: ruby, google-oauth, gmail-api, query-string

I am trying to send query parameters to fetch list of messages via gmail api `https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list`

Here is my code

```
message_list = gmail.list_user_messages user_id
```

It returns the message list
response -

```
"messages": [
{
"id": "16641115eca503dc",
"threadId": "16641115eca503dc"
},
```

Now I want to pass the query parameters

```
params = {userId: 'me',
      maxResults: 1,
      pageToken: pageToken}

message_list = gmail.list_user_messages(params)
```

But it is not working as expected. Please share the correct way to add query parameters.

Comment: please post [example]

Answer (score 2):

Go to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list). Use ****'Try this API'**** option and there you can learn about query params like `'is:unread'` ,`'from:some@abc.com'` etc.

[image: Try this API Google API]

If you want to know about more about valid query strings like `'is:unread'` then you can use gmail search options and generate valid query strings.

[image]

Edit: [Search operator documentation](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190)